# Which SATA cable do I need for a SSD installation in an iMac mid-2011?

Tags: hard-drive, imac, hardware, ssd

1) which  SATA cable speed do I need for a SSD installment in a iMac mid-2011? In OWC or iFixit kits, they uses SATA 3, but today I can get quicker SATA 6 cables, does that work or make it quicker?

2) do I need a data power splitter or just without splitter? I don't know where I need the power from.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By SATA 6, I assume you mean SATA 6Gb/s. This is [now known](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8142/~/difference-between-sata-i%2C-sata-ii-and-sata-iii) as SATA 3. (In fact SATA 3Gb/s, is [now known as](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8142/~/difference-between-sata-i%2C-sata-ii-and-sata-iii) SATA 2.)  SATA 3 has been around since [2009](https://sata-io.org/sites/default/files/documents/SATA-Revision-3.0-Press-Release-FINAL-052609.pdf), and is [backwards compatible](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/8142/~/difference-between-sata-i%2C-sata-ii-and-sata-iii) with SATA 2, so a SATA 3 cable is fine. Also SSDs need both a power AND a data cable to function.

Apparently it is possible to add a second hard drive to this model of Mac (behind the CD drive). You do not state in the question if you merely wish to replace the hard drive you already have or add a second one. This Ifixit [guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+iMac+Intel+21.5-Inch+EMC+2428+Dual+Hard+Drive+Kit/6434) shows how to add a second drive. From the guide it is clear that this is a MAJOR undertaking.

If you simply wish to replace the drive you already have, as seen [here](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iMac+Intel+21.5-Inch+EMC+2428+Teardown/5485), then you should have an easier time. However, according to the Ifixit [guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iMac+Intel+21.5-Inch+EMC+2428+Teardown/5485) (step 7)

> The WD Caviar Blue drive is a non-standard SATA drive. The power connector features 7 pins, rather than the standard 4. The drive also has non-standard firmware. This means you can only use Apple's own hard drives and not any standard after-market SATA drive.

Thus you need to choose a compatible new drive. In this case you can just reuse the cables from the old drive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wanted to put the sad behind the logical drive 1) if I replace the logical drive with the SSD, can I then just use the cables from the logical drive? 2) I bought a kingston 120 SSD, that I also put in my macbook pro from mid 2012. Can't I use this SSD in my Imac mid 2011? Thanks again

Comment: 1) Yes. 
2) I have a 2011 Macbook Pro (the non retina), which uses a standard SSD.   The 2012 non-retina Mabook Pro is identical, and thus also uses a standard SSD. However as I said in my post

"according to the Ifixit guide (step 7)

'The WD Caviar Blue drive is a non-standard SATA drive. The power connector features 7 pins, rather than the standard 4. The drive also has non-standard firmware. This means you can only use Apple's own hard drives and not any standard after-market SATA drive.' " ... So no, it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The sata cable you are looking for is called:

Slimline SATA cable SATA 22 pin to 13 pin Cable SATA Female to Female

You can buy it here (it was the cheapest option I could find):
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/25cm-Slimline-SATA-cable-SATA-22-pin-to-13-pin-Cable-SATA-Female-to-Female-converter/32830204299.html?spm=a2g0s.13010208.99999999.267.65f33c00IorXXe

You need to plug it into the sata port behind your logic board and then connect it to the SSD, which you can mount behind the Optical Drive.

Theres a tutorial on how to do that here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIULGZHw8xI

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the optical drive with an SSD just as i did in my 2011 iMac, just buy a "SATA 2nd HDD SSD Hard Drive Caddy for 12.7mm Universal CD / DVD-ROM", put the SSD in and replace the optical drive using its cables. The only thing you have to move is the temperature sensor. Done it in 10 minutes with cleaning. The cable supports the maximum speed your SATA port does, so there's no point in replacing it. Everything else is a lot more complicated. If you need an optical drive, just mount it in an external USB housing and connect it to your USB port.