# What SSD drives are compatible with a 2011 Mac Mini?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, mac-mini

I currently have 2 x 1Tb hard drives in my Mac Mini, but would like to upgrade them to make the computer faster.

**Are there some 1Tb SSD drives that I should avoid? Are there some that are recommended?
Do they need a specific enclosure to be fitted in?**

Some SSD are $60 for 2Tb and some are $400. I would love something in between so I don't ruin myself.

Answer (score 2):

Most SATA 3 SSDs should work fine. But they must be 2.5" form factor and not more than 9.5mm high.

But have a read of [EveryMac](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/mac-mini-aluminum-unibody-faq/how-to-upgrade-hard-drive-aluminum-unibody-mac-mini.html)'s article on this topic. At the end EveryMac advises to get one from a supplier that guarantees the SSD works with your MacMini. Find your own supplier or follow the links to their associated suppliers - like this one [OWC](https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/ssd/owc/mac-mini/2011).

If you haven't opening the Mini before, do watch the videos on how to do this.  Again some links in EveryMac article.

Comment: Does a SATA 3 SSD need an adapter to go in the Mac Mini 2011? Or can I just plug it in directly?

Comment: I have not done an SSD install in the Mini, but OWC sell complete kits and the videos should indicate what is needed.

Comment: thank you. I was just wondering if there were cheaper options than OWC. One of their HD for the Mini is around $1k 

Comment: If you already have 2 HDDs, then I would assume you could swap a HDD for SSD, without purchasing any additional hardware. At least, this is what is shown in one of the videos.

Comment: Also, I think Gilby should have included the SSD should have a 2.5" form factor and be no greater than 9.5 mm high. Although, I think most SATA SSDs are 2.5" and 7 mm high.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks, I have added that to the answer.

Comment: @MicroMachine I see US$229 for 1 TB kit at OWC, and US$359 for 2TB.  And note David's comment given you already have 2 HDD installed.

Comment: @DavidAnderson on [this page] (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285189/which-sata-cable-do-i-need-for-a-ssd-installation-in-an-imac-mid-2011) it says that the SSD needs to have 4 pins on one end instead of 7 pins. I am not finding any Sata3 SSD internal hard drives with 4 pins anywhere...

Comment: MicroMachine: The [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285189/which-sata-cable-do-i-need-for-a-ssd-installation-in-an-imac-mid-2011) in your previous comment is to a question about a 2011 iMac. However, the [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/439514/what-ssd-drives-are-compatible-with-a-2011-mac-mini) you posted is for a 2011 Mac mini. The 2011 iMac models and the 2011 Mac mini models use different drive cables. I can not find any evidence the 2011 Mac mini models have any special pin requirements for the internal SATA drives. I there something I am missing here?